# Why would I choose a Windows Service over a Web API service?

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api, microservices

For me, Windows Services are inconvenient and cumbersome enough to question their validity in all apps that aren't "Watch this folder for a change, react to this change."

I understand that this oversimplification is ignorant, why would one choose a windows service over the Web API.

Comment: Internal server management, automation, event tracing/chaining... not everything is web-based... why would you call a web API to poll/react to  the windows event log?  Or any other number of internal operations that services are used for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every time you have something that isn't activated by a HTTP request?

To get a hint, run `services.msc` from `WIN+R` (run program). Go through the services and try to see if all could be hosted within IIS instead.

If not: Well, there is your answer.

> I do believe we can skate by the reboot issue with our centralized monitoring service, as well as the IIS "never go down" module. I've chosen to leave the service as a Windows Service while I automate his deployment, however I'm not completely convinced it's worth the inconvenience of install -> attach debugger -> make change -> start/stop -> attach debugger -> flail when debugger fails because service locks a file, etc

imho it's much more fragile to depend on a monitoring service and a always on module when you have stuff for that already built into windows (monitoring = windows event log).

As for debugging windows services, they are easy to debug with a small adaptation in  Program.cs. I've written about it here: http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/09/05/an-easier-way-to-debug-windows-services/

Comment: OK, now we're cooking. Say I have a self hosted Web API running within a Windows Service. If he were to also subscribe to a message queue, would it just be a terrible idea to let him just be a web service?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you can keep the application pool and IIS running? What happens at a reboot? IIS typically only starts an app when the first request arrives. It will then be taken down when being idle. That means that your message queue will not be read other than then. With a windows service you know for sure that it boots with Windows and goes down properly when wndows shuts down.

Comment: I do believe we can skate by the reboot issue with our centralized monitoring service, as well as the IIS "never go down" module. I've chosen to leave the service as a Windows Service while I automate his deployment, however I'm not completely convinced it's worth the inconvenience of install -> attach debugger -> make change -> start/stop -> attach debugger -> flail when debugger fails because service locks a file, etc.

Comment: Hey thanks, I appreciate your time

Comment: Much agreed... you're essentially trying to build a service on top of a service for the purpose of what the service you're building on top of serves... and hoping it will be stable, for ease of debugging.  Better to stick closer to the metal (or OS at least) with services, IMO (nice blog post on debugging, btw)